# V-model works locally fine, make error deployed on Netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, netlify

I have a parent component:

```
 <formInput
      :inputType="text"
      v-model="email"
      :class="{ ' border-green-400': isValidEmail }"
    ></formInput>
```

And the code of formInput:

```
<template>
  <input
    v-model="inputModel"
    required
    type="inputType"
    class="rounded-3xl border-2 bg-red-100 bg-transparent px-1 py-2 text-xl shadow-lg transition-all duration-300 hover:border-blue-400 active:border-blue-400"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineModel, defineProps } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps(['inputType'])
const inputModel = defineModel()
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

It works locally just fine, but deployed on Netlify, i get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

because of the

```
import { defineModel, defineProps } from 'vue'
 v-model="inputModel"
const inputModel = defineModel()
```

After trial and error method i found out that the model, that provides component v-model and works just fine locally, doesnt work on netlify?
If i delete the model, the whole app works just fine.

Comment: Don't call functions directly, instead pass them by reference. When you have `@click="loginUser()"` this method is being called immediately. Instead, just do `@click="loginUser"` and it should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks sir for the idea, but it didnt work. The error disapread, when i deleted the import statements of my components, so when theres  // import formInput from './formInput.vue' it works, but with no comment it doesnt.

Comment: Show the contents of the `form-input` component

Comment: thanks sir, i edited the question and provided the code.

Comment: what are you using to build your production code?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy This is not true. You can bind a function call with parenthesis, Vue will just wrap it around an anonymous function to avoid the immediate invocation. If Vue sees the binded values is a function reference, then it doesn't need to wrap it.

Comment: you shouldn't need to import defineModel or defineProps.  What exact version of Vue are you running?  If you can, bump Vue to >= 3.4 and remove the import statement.  The upgrade may help things